# React-datepicker openToDate not working

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I'm trying to use [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) in my project and I have it wrapped so I can easily use it with redux but the `openToDate` prop doesn't seem to be doing anything. Has any one else experienced this and/or found a fix/workaround.

Here's my control

```
export function renderDatePicker ({input, placeholder, defaultValue, meta: {touched, error}, ...custom }){
return (
    <div className="form-group">
        <DatePicker
            {...input}
            {...custom}
            dateFormat="MMDDYYYY"
            selected={input.value ? input.value : null}
            placeholderText={placeholder ? placeholder : ''}
            isClearable={!custom.disabled}
            className="form-control" />
        {touched && error && <span className="error">{error}</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And how I use it...

```
<Field name="StartdDate"
   component={renderDatePicker}
   openToDate={this.props.minDate}
   minDate={this.props.minDate}
   maxDate={this.props.maxDate}
   placeholder="Select Start Date"
   showMonthDropdown
   showYearDropdown />
```

Most of my use cases limit the selectable dates to previous years and limit it to only that year (i.e January 1, 1990 - December 31 1990). So always opening to the current date is kind of annoying, which is why I'd like `openToDate` to open to the minimum allowed date. For some reason though it always opens to the current date.

The only way I got it to open to the min date was to set `selected` to default to `defaultValue` and pass in `this.props.minDate` as the defaultValue. But I don't want the date to be pre-selected.

Answer (score 1):

I found that downgrading the version to `v.0.40.0` fixes the problem and opens to the `openToDate` value or the `maxDate` if no `openToDate` is set.

Comment: that's not really a great solution